# Fancy Header applies wrong header to all pages following list of tables

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I've been at this for well over an hour, trying to track down WHY every page following my list of tables page gets its header from list of tables. Can anyone help me?

```
%-----------------Einrichten-Papier-----------------%

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}           % Artikelklasse mit Schriftgröße 11 auf A4-Format (1-Seitig (Für zweiseitig: "twoside"))

%-----------------Pakete-Laden-----------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            % Erweiterung der Zeichenkodierung um Worttrennung bei  Umlauten zu ermöglichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Direkte Eingabe von dt. Umlauten/Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{vmargin}                                % Spalteneinzug nach Adsatz = 0
\usepackage{nextpage}                               % Um leere Seiten zu erzeugen
\usepackage{listings}                               % Quelltext einbinden
\usepackage{booktabs}                               % Linienstile verwenden
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               % Seitenlayout (Kopf- und Fußzeile)
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ae}                                     % Auflösung der Schrift erhöhen
\usepackage{textcomp}                               % Nutzung von Sonderzeichen --> \texteuro für Währung
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}        
\usepackage{subcaption}                     
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,mathrsfs}       % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}                      % weiterer Mathematischer Zeichensatz
\usepackage{array}                                  % Zur Nutzung von Tabulatoren als Platzhalter(Ähnlich Tabellenumgebung)
\usepackage{tabularx}                               % Tabellenerstellung
\usepackage{multirow}                               % in Tabelle mehrere Kästchen einer Zeile verbinden
\usepackage{nomencl}                                % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}                        % Einbinden von PDF 
\usepackage{tocstyle}                               % mach im Inhaltsverzeichnis Punkte zwischen der Schrift und der Seite
\usepackage{pdflscape}                              % PDFs können gedreht werden und anders formtiert
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{times}                                  % Schriftart
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unit-mode=text]{siunitx}                % Einhieten nicht kursiv
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[
nonumberlist, %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,      %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,          %Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
section]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{Listings}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother


%--------------Seiteneinstellungen--------------%

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                             % Einzug am Absatzbeginn in mm
\setmarginsrb           {40mm}                          % linker Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % oberer Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % rechter Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % unterer Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {32pt}                          % Headerhöhe
                        {7.5mm}                         % Abstand zwischen Header und Textbody [Abstand in mm]
                        {32pt}                          % Footerhöhe [Abstand in mm]
                        {7.5mm}                         % Abstand zwischen Footer und Textbody [Abstand in mm]

%--------------Header und Footer Design--------------%

\pagestyle{fancy}                               % eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{}                                      % alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{}                                 % Kopfzeile links
\fancyhead[C]{}                                 % zentrierte Kopfzeile
\fancyhead[R]{\small\leftmark}                  % Kopfzeile rechts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}            % obere Trennlinie
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}                         % Seitennummer
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}           % untere Trennlinie
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}             % alle Kopfzeilen kleingeschrieben


%---------------Symbolverzeichnis im Glossary Style----------------%

\newglossarystyle{listdottedskip}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[]\makebox[0.5\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##1}{##2}%
            \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}\parbox[t]{\textwidth-0.5\glslistdottedwidth-\labelsep}{##3}}%\hss. stat 5em
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        \item[]\makebox[0.5\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##2}{##3}%
            \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##4}%
}


%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren glossar
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\makeglossaries
\newglossarystyle{Symbolverzeichnis}{
    %% Umgebung: longtable
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{longtable}{@{}ccp{6cm}p{6cm}@{}}}
        {\end{longtable}} %Tabellenkopf
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Name} \\
        \endhead}
    % keine Überschriften zwischen Gruppen
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    % Haupteinträge in einer Zeile:
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[4]{
        \glsentryuseri{##1}     % Symbol
        & \si{\glsentryuserii{##1}}     % Einheit
        & \glstarget{##1}{##2}      % Name
        & ##3       % Description
        \\      % Zeilenende
    }
    % Untereinträge wie Haupteinträge
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{
        \glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}
    % nichts zwischen Gruppen
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

% XXX
\newglossarystyle{physeinheiten}{
%
% Umgebung: longtable
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
%
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}ccp{12cm}p{6cm}@{}}}
%
{\end{longtable}}
%
% Tabellenkopf
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
%
\textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Name} \\
\endhead}
%
% keine Überschriften zwischen Gruppen
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
%
% Haupteinträge in einer Zeile:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[4]{
%
 \glstarget{##1}{##2}
% Symbol
& \si{\glsentryuserii{##1}}
% Einheit
& \glsentryuseri{##1}
% Name

\\
% Zeilenende
}
%
% Untereinträge wie Haupteinträge
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{
%
\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}
%
% nichts zwischen Gruppen
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
%
}






%----------------------Start-Dokument--------------------------%
\loadglsentries{Dokumente/glossar}
\begin{document}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}                             % Seitenzahl aus

    \include{Dokumente/Deckblatt}               % Einbinden des Deckblattes
    \include{Dokumente/disclaimer}              % Danksagung, Eidesstattliche Erklärung, Sperrvermerk

    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}                     % Seitenanzahl an
    \pagenumbering{roman}                       % Seitenanzahl in klein roman
    \tableofcontents                            % Inhaltsverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \listoffigures                              % Abbildungsverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \listoftables                               % Tabellenverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \include{Dokumente/content}


    \setcounter{page}{1}                        % Seitanzahl wieder auf 1
    \pagenumbering{Roman}                       % Seitenanzahl in groß roman
    \include{Dokumente/Anhang}

        \printglossary[type=symbolslist,title=Symbolverzeichnis,style=physeinheiten]
        \newpage
    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
        \newpage
        \deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abk"urzungsverzeichnis}
        \setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.2\linewidth}
        \printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype,title=Abk"urzungsverzeichnis] %altlist    listdottedskip ,style=listdottedskip
        \newpage
    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
        \newpage
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
        \deftranslation[to=German]{Glossary}{Glossar}
        \printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossar]%
        \newpage%


    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}   % im Inhaltsverzeichnis anzeigen
%   \bibliographystyle{alphadin}                % Stil des Literaturverzeichnisses
    \bibliographystyle{plain}   
    \bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to the question but `\usepackage{ae}` should be used in any documents since real 8-bit fonts were produced (in 1990 or some such date)  In your case it's not used at all as you reset the fonts to Times with `\usepackage{times} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using the options of your class and not `fancyhdr` package:

```
%-----------------Einrichten-Papier-----------------%

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}           % Artikelklasse mit Schriftgröße 11 auf A4-Format (1-Seitig (Für zweiseitig: "twoside"))

%-----------------Pakete-Laden-----------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            % Erweiterung der Zeichenkodierung um Worttrennung bei  Umlauten zu ermöglichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Direkte Eingabe von dt. Umlauten/Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{vmargin}                                % Spalteneinzug nach Adsatz = 0
\usepackage{nextpage}                               % Um leere Seiten zu erzeugen
\usepackage{listings}                               % Quelltext einbinden
\usepackage{booktabs}                               % Linienstile verwenden
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               % Seitenlayout (Kopf- und Fußzeile)
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ae}                                     % Auflösung der Schrift erhöhen
\usepackage{textcomp}                               % Nutzung von Sonderzeichen --> \texteuro für Währung
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}        
\usepackage{subcaption}                     
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,mathrsfs}       % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}                      % weiterer Mathematischer Zeichensatz
\usepackage{array}                                  % Zur Nutzung von Tabulatoren als Platzhalter(Ähnlich Tabellenumgebung)
\usepackage{tabularx}                               % Tabellenerstellung
\usepackage{multirow}                               % in Tabelle mehrere Kästchen einer Zeile verbinden
\usepackage{nomencl}                                % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}                        % Einbinden von PDF 
\usepackage{tocstyle}                               % mach im Inhaltsverzeichnis Punkte zwischen der Schrift und der Seite
\usepackage{pdflscape}                              % PDFs können gedreht werden und anders formtiert
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{times}                                  % Schriftart
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[unit-mode=text]{siunitx}                % Einhieten nicht kursiv
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[
nonumberlist, %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
acronym,      %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,          %Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
section]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{Listings}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother


%--------------Seiteneinstellungen--------------%

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                             % Einzug am Absatzbeginn in mm
\setmarginsrb           {40mm}                          % linker Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % oberer Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % rechter Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {20mm}                          % unterer Rand [Abstand in mm]
                        {32pt}                          % Headerhöhe
                        {7.5mm}                         % Abstand zwischen Header und Textbody [Abstand in mm]
                        {32pt}                          % Footerhöhe [Abstand in mm]
                        {7.5mm}                         % Abstand zwischen Footer und Textbody [Abstand in mm]

%--------------Header und Footer Design--------------%
\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{section}
\cfoot{}
\ohead{\leftmark}
\ofoot{Page~\Roman{page}}


\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}             % alle Kopfzeilen kleingeschrieben


%---------------Symbolverzeichnis im Glossary Style----------------%

\newglossarystyle{listdottedskip}{%
    \glossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
        \item[]\makebox[0.5\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##1}{##2}%
            \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}\parbox[t]{\textwidth-0.5\glslistdottedwidth-\labelsep}{##3}}%\hss. stat 5em
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
        \item[]\makebox[0.5\glslistdottedwidth][l]{\glstarget{##2}{##3}%
            \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut}##4}%
}


%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren glossar
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\makeglossaries
\newglossarystyle{Symbolverzeichnis}{
    %% Umgebung: longtable
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {\begin{longtable}{@{}ccp{6cm}p{6cm}@{}}}
        {\end{longtable}} %Tabellenkopf
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Name} \\
        \endhead}
    % keine Überschriften zwischen Gruppen
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    % Haupteinträge in einer Zeile:
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[4]{
        \glsentryuseri{##1}     % Symbol
        & \si{\glsentryuserii{##1}}     % Einheit
        & \glstarget{##1}{##2}      % Name
        & ##3       % Description
        \\      % Zeilenende
    }
    % Untereinträge wie Haupteinträge
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{
        \glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}
    % nichts zwischen Gruppen
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
}

% XXX
\newglossarystyle{physeinheiten}{
%
% Umgebung: longtable
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
%
  {\begin{longtable}{@{}ccp{12cm}p{6cm}@{}}}
%
{\end{longtable}}
%
% Tabellenkopf
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
%
\textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Einheit} & \textbf{Name} \\
\endhead}
%
% keine Überschriften zwischen Gruppen
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
%
% Haupteinträge in einer Zeile:
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[4]{
%
 \glstarget{##1}{##2}
% Symbol
& \si{\glsentryuserii{##1}}
% Einheit
& \glsentryuseri{##1}
% Name

\\
% Zeilenende
}
%
% Untereinträge wie Haupteinträge
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{
%
\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}}
%
% nichts zwischen Gruppen
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
%
}






%----------------------Start-Dokument--------------------------%
%\loadglsentries{Dokumente/glossar}
\begin{document}
    %\fancyfoot[R]{}                             % Seitenzahl aus

    \include{Dokumente/Deckblatt}               % Einbinden des Deckblattes
    \include{Dokumente/disclaimer}              % Danksagung, Eidesstattliche Erklärung, Sperrvermerk

%    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}                     % Seitenanzahl an
    \pagenumbering{roman}                       % Seitenanzahl in klein roman
    \tableofcontents                            % Inhaltsverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \listoffigures                              % Abbildungsverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \listoftables                               % Tabellenverzeichnis
    \newpage
    \include{Dokumente/content}


    \setcounter{page}{1}                        % Seitanzahl wieder auf 1
    \pagenumbering{Roman}                       % Seitenanzahl in groß roman
    \include{Dokumente/Anhang}

        \printglossary[type=symbolslist,title=Symbolverzeichnis,style=physeinheiten]
        \newpage
    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
        \newpage
        \deftranslation[to=German]{Acronyms}{Abk"urzungsverzeichnis}
        \setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.2\linewidth}
        \printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype,title=Abk"urzungsverzeichnis] %altlist    listdottedskip ,style=listdottedskip
        \newpage
    % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
        \newpage
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
        \deftranslation[to=German]{Glossary}{Glossar}
        \printglossary[style=altlist,title=Glossar]%
        \newpage%


    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}   % im Inhaltsverzeichnis anzeigen
%   \bibliographystyle{alphadin}                % Stil des Literaturverzeichnisses
    \bibliographystyle{plain}   
    \bibliography{references}

\section{test}
test
\end{document}
```

I used your not so minimal WE in order to let you check it in your real file... but this is not the recommended way for this site.

Comment: Notice that your included files, has to contain a section to change the haeder and also that `\section[Sort Header and TOC]{Long Section}` will work for header too

Comment: It was that the include files didn't have the changed header! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome @ItsAnApe... Have a nice day.